# Oracle Query how to count column range that has value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question guys, is it possible to count rows in column range (Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, Column 5) that has value?

[image]

select a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12 from table1;

like the image above it should return like this:
[image]

Comment: `quick ans`, little bit more details required....it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: also, what have you tried?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data, expected outcome and what have you tried?

Comment: @SimonPrice I tried using count("ColumnName") then it counts all in that column, what I want is to count the number of columns in that row that has a value.

Comment: Good that you have added images but still it is unclear. Add data here. No images please

Comment: @Tejash that's the data there in the image, I want to count those that has value in it.

Comment: please dont put data in images, please go to sql fiddle and create a replicable issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT T.*, 
CASE WHEN A2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN A3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN A4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN A5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN A6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN A7 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
AS CNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
```

This query will return not-null column's count of that row.

Cheers!!